# How to describe the function operation "composition", $\circ$, using the convention of function notation.

Tags: functions, notation

I am in the process of reading Tao's *Analysis I* after completing Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* (pretty new to maths).

It recently occurred to me that all operations, ($+,*, $ etc), seem to behave like functions. This made me think about the function operation of **composition**, $\circ$, and how one could possibly define composition in the convention of function notation.

I've been playing around with the notation a little bit, and this is what I have so far.

Firstly, I'm pretty certain that composition behaves as a binary operation, and the domain is effectively the set of all ordered pairs of all functions (which I will call $T \times T$...where $T$ by itself is simply the set of all functions). From what I can tell, the only proposition $P(f,g)$ that needs to be fulfilled for composition is: $\forall x \in \operatorname {dom}(f), f(x) \in \operatorname{dom}(g)$.

Therefore, we have the following definition of composition:

$\circ : T \times T \to T$

$(f,g)\mapsto h$ s.t. $\forall x \in \operatorname {dom}(f), f(x) \in \operatorname{dom}(g)$

I'm sure this is probably incorrect, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

After reading some of the comments, it seems like I need to make the following change:

> $(f,g) \mapsto h=g(f(x))$ s.t. $\forall x \in \operatorname {dom}(f), f(x) \in \operatorname{dom}(g)$

Comment: You should probably look up the category of sets, i.e., $\textbf{Set}$.

Comment: Given the notation $B^A$ for "the set of functions $A \to B$", one can consider the only possible function with the following type: $$\circ : B^A \times C^B \to C^A$$

Comment: See [Composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations).

Comment: " From what I can tell, the only proposition P(f,g) that needs to be fulfilled for composition is: ∀x∈dom(f),f(x)∈dom(g)." That tells the requirement to allow for the composition to be possible.  It doesn't say anything about what the composition *IS*.  Afterall  if $g:X\to Y$ and $f:Y\to Z$ then $f\circ g: X\to Z$ but if $h: X\to Z$ we have no reason to believe $h = f\circ g$.  There are *many* functions $X\to Z$ and they aren't *ALL* $f\circ g$.

Comment: This is fine for the most part:  If $A^B=\{f:A\to B\}$ and $B^C=\{f:B\to C\}$ then $\circ:A^B\times B^C\to A^C$ but that only tells the domain and codomain of $\circ$.  It doesnt tell what $\circ$ is.  This would be the equivalent of define $\sin$ as "Definition:  $\sin:\mathbb R\to [-1,1]$".  We need $\circ(f,g): x\in A\mapsto f(g(x))\in C$.

Comment: @fleablood that makes a lot of sense! Is my edit correct? (I think based on how I defined the domains and ranges, it needs to read as $g(f(x))$ ) Cheers~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition is fine if you just modify composition to be a function from the set
$$\{(f,g) \in T\times T : x\in \operatorname{dom}(f) \Rightarrow f(x)\in \operatorname{dom}(g)\}$$
but this is a somewhat unusual way to axiomatize composition as an operation. More typical is that one regards a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ to have a fixed domain ($A$) and a fixed *codomain* ($B$) which may be different (larger) than the image $f(A)$. Functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow D$ can then only be composed as $g\circ f$ if $B=C$.

This is a bit counterintuitive at first since it means that you wouldn't be allowed to compose a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ with a function $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as $g\circ f$ since the codomain of $f$ doesn't match the domain of $g$, even though it's a subset. The fix to this is to note that since $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\subseteq \mathbb R$ there is an *inclusion* map $\iota : \mathbb R_{\geq 0}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ define by $\iota(x)=x$. Then, we can compose $g\circ \iota \circ f$ as desired.

This definition is convenient because it turns out that sometimes we really do care about the codomain - for instance, in linear algebra, there's a notion of duality where you can take a map $f:V\rightarrow W$ and "reverse" it into a map $f^*:W^*\rightarrow V^*$ called the adjoint of $f$, where different codomains would give different adjoints - hence we have to record the codomain. In algebraic topology, the codomain sometimes matters since if you take a circle and map by inclusion it into a plane, the circle can suddenly be shrunk to a point, which it couldn't before - meaning that an inclusion map did something meaningful and that we shouldn't ignore it.

Then, essentially, composition can be defined by first choosing some collection of functions $T$ and a collection of possible domains and codomains $O$, and letting $\operatorname{dom},\operatorname{codom}:T\rightarrow O$ be functions taking a function to their domain and codomain respectively. Composition is then defined to have the domain of
$$\{(g,f) \in T\times T : \operatorname{dom}(g) = \operatorname{codom}(f)\}$$
and an output in $T$ such that $\operatorname{dom}(g\circ f) =\operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $\operatorname{codom}(g\circ f)=\operatorname{codom}(g)$ and such that $h\circ (g\circ f)=(h\circ g)\circ f$. One also desires that for every possible object $o$ in $O$ there be some identity map $\operatorname{id}_o$ such that $f\circ \operatorname{id}_o = f$ and $\operatorname{id}_o\circ f = f$ whenever these compositions are legal. These definitions describe a *category* - and "functions between sets" is one example of a category, but there turns out to be a lot of other examples, in the same way that "the integers" is an example of a ring, but not the only one - for instance, there's a category of vector spaces with linear maps between them and a category of topological spaces with continuous maps between them, all satisfying this same general setup for composition.